# javascript to external .js file

Tags: javascript, file, external

Can't figure out the proper syntax to place this javascript code into a .js file.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://hostedusa3.whoson.com:8080/include.js?domain=www.yourdomain.com'></script>    
<script type='text/javascript' >
if(typeof sWOTrackPage=='function')sWOTrackPage();
</script>
```

Comment: What do you want in the .js file?  Where is this file located?  What does "enter code here" mean?

Comment: @ScottHunter, `enter code here` is inputed by the question/answer editor when you hit the Code Sample button or Ctrl+K and havent selected text first, OP probably just forgot to delete it

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the inline code inside a separate file, then all you have to do is move the contents of the second `script` tag into a `.js` file. Then, set the `src` attribute to the second `<script>` to reference the new file's URL (relative or absolute).

Answer (score 0):

external.js:

```
if(typeof sWOTrackPage=='function')sWOTrackPage();
```

in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
```

---

If you want the other stuff in there to.  Use your browser.  Goto: `http://hostedusa3.whoson.com:8080/include.js?domain=www.yourdomain.com` copy that into external.js